# How to set a WooCommerce email template as default for all emails

Tags: wordpress, email, templates, woocommerce

I’m looking for a way to send all WordPress emails using a custom WooCommerce template so all emails will look the same.

The path to the template would be:

```
woocommerce/emails/my-custom-woocommerce-template.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it *have* to all be templatized in a single file? If not, a combination of these entry points can probably get you the standardization you're looking for:

1. `email-header.php` lets you customize the start of the email including the header image (if you need to do more than change its URL). It opens the layout tags for the rest of the email content
2. `email-footer.php` lets you customize the footer, and closes the layout tags started in the header.
3. `email-styles.php` or the `woocommerce_email_styles` filter let you customize the CSS (see some gotchas in my article [here](https://www.mail-mechanic.com/woocommerce-email-css)).
4. Various actions/filters are scattered throughout the emails for customizing individual parts.

Comment: Thanks @dan-wich, many emails can be send from different plugins and I’m not able to configure each ones, a nice solution for me would be to set a template as default for all WP sends.

Comment: I saw on the other answer that you found a solution with the Email Templates plugin. You might still need to edit the files I mentioned so that your emails don't get doubly-wrapped in template code (wrapped from that plugin, and then with the WooCommerce header/footer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below function. It is working

```
function myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // List of all templates that should be replaced with custom template
    $woo_templates = array( 
        'emails/admin-new-order.php',
        'emails/admin-failed-order.php',
        'emails/admin-cancelled-order.php',
        'emails/customer-completed-order.php',
        'emails/customer-new-account.php',
        'emails/customer-note.php',
        'emails/customer-on-hold-order.php',
        'emails/customer-processing-order.php',
        'emails/customer-refunded-order.php',
        'emails/customer-reset-password.php',
    );
    //Check whether template is in replacable template array

    if( in_array( $template_name, $woo_templates ) ){

        // Set your custom template path
        $template = your_template_path.'emails/my-custom-woocommerce-template';
    }

    // Return what we found
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you @melvin, it looks like what i’m looking for, the problem is that i don’t know the names of all templates to put in the list, for example some emails are sending via Ninja Forms. Would there be a way to set a template for all sends without exception?

Comment: @jjj The above array contains all the default email template names that are send by WooCommerce. I am not aware of the template names of Emails send via njnia forms because i haven't used before

Comment: so I have to list all the names of emails sending via the system (WP, WC and plugins)... I understand the method, it is a good one but I’ll continue to look for  a more flexible solution.

Comment: @jjj Yes. unfortunately you have to. It would be helpful if you can upvote my answer for my efforts. I will post you if i get a more flexible solution.

Comment: yes for sure, I will and I appreciate a lot your efforts and your help, thanks again.

Comment: @jjj Will update you once i have a more flexible solution.

Comment: The actual working solution I found is the use of the “Email Templates” plugin with an additional hook to relocated template from the plugin to the theme.

Comment: @jjj glad you have a solution

Comment: Finally I still looking for a more flexible solution.

Comment: @jjj What happened to the plugin you found ?

Comment: Emails from WC are sent without template :/

Comment: @jjj Most plugin extend WooCommerce emails in their plugin folder inside a folde name email which will give path like email/some_template_name.php. So the above solution will work without any issues. The only work is to add path to the array.

Comment: @jjj I have an idea in mind but haven't tested which is why i am not able to give you any update. You can access woocommerce emails class which will give you all available email objects. Third party plugins also uses this same class. So you will have all email objects available. You can set the template path in this object after looping. I haven't got time to test this. I will surely check this weekend

Comment: would be nice if you can have a test, thanks for your comments and for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'your_wp_mail_action' ); //  $args = compact( 'to', 'subject', 'message', 'headers', 'attachments' )
function your_wp_mail_action( $args ) {
    global $your_prefix_your_email_args; // the args you could use in my-custom-woocommerce-template file

    $your_prefix_your_email_args = $args;

    ob_clean();
    get_template_part( 'woocommerce/emails/my-custom-woocommerce-template' );

    $args['message'] = ob_get_clean();

    // ... your logic

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please improve it a little more because I can't make it work, only have the template without styles and message.

Answer (score 0):

To view and update email settings, log into your website dashboard. In the left-hand menu, click on WooCommerce → Settings.

There, you’ll find several options tabs at the top. Click Emails to view the following templates

you can custom all as you want

Comment: The question is about emails sent outside the WooCommerce emails system.